# Test full path to folder exists without relying on exception

Tags: c++, exception, uwp, storage

I am working on a C++ UWP / WinRT application,
and would like to test whether a given string represents a path to an extant folder, and I would like to do it without relying on catching an exception. Motivation at bottom.

Looking through the [UWP Storage API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.Storage), it seems like the only routine along these lines which does not use exceptions to communicate success is `TryGetItemAsync()`, which unfortunately requires having a `StorageFolder` in-hand, and the only way I've seen to get a `StorageFolder` from a full path string is via `GetFolderFromPathAsync()`, which uses exceptions to communicate failure.

Motivation: it's just a nit. Even when caught, the exception gets logged in Output and makes it look like things are failing, which slows down development.  Perhaps I need to catch it in some more vigorous manner.

---

Edit to include example comparing stock C++ code to UWP:

```
void cppTestFolder(const std::wstring path)
{
    bool existsCpp = !!(std::ifstream(path));
    bool existsUwp = UWP_Based_TestFolder(path);

    LogW(std::wstring(L"folder path exists ?  CPP: ") + (existsCpp ? L"yes" : L"no ") + L"  UWP: " + (existsUwp ? L"yes" : L"no ") + L"   path: " + path);
}

...
    cppTestFolder(L"C:\\Data");
    cppTestFolder(L"C:\\Data\\no_such_folder");
...

and logging output: (minus the annoying exception messages I want to avoid)

folder path exists ?  CPP: no  UWP: yes  path: C:\Data
folder path exists ?  CPP: no  UWP: no   path: C:\Data\no_such_folder
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Test full path to folder exists without relying on exception

I'm afraid you can't check the folder exists without relying on exception. You could refer the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.storage.storagefolder.getfolderfrompathasync?view=winrt-20348#exceptions). It is recommend way that check the folder relying on exception. As you mentioned above `TryGetItemAsync` is not static method, so it need a base folder instance.

For this scenario, the only way for checking the folder with path is using desktop-bridge. And process the folder checking in desktop extension and send back the result to UWP client. Desktop extension has no such limits, you could use [File.Exists](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.exists?view=net-5.0) api to check storage item.  For desktop bridge you could refer stefan' bolg **UWP with Desktop Extension**.

Comment: I am afraid you can. Refer my answer below :)

Comment: Have you tested, does it work in UWP platform ?

Comment: No test on this platform, but my C++ is standard C++

Comment: Yep, I know that, but uwp is run in the sandbox, and it has special storage access limitation